# How to schedule an android service to execute at a fixed rate

Tags: android, android-service

I am working on an application that should download a file from the network every X seconds to check for any change, I use a service to do that, but its execution is not fixed with the delay time rate, here is my code for the service:

---

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    checkUpdate();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private Void checkUpdate() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Service", String.valueOf(++counter));
                if(Helper.isNetworkAvailable(getBaseContext())) {
                      // download file
                } else {
                        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                    }
                }else {
                    Log.e("Connection", "No connection");
                }
            }
        }, 10000, 10000);
    return null;
}
```

---

The output isn't fixed, it is supposed to run every 10 seconds, while running the service run in a random manner

Comment: and what is not working with your current code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting up an AlarmManager within an IntentService? Much more accurate.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourClass.class);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pi);
```

Make sure within YourClass.class (which is an IntentService), put your logic in the handleIntent(Intent intent), which will be called every 10 seconds by the PendingIntent sent by the AlarmManager.

P.S. Update your manifest

Hope it helps

Comment: Even that I was using a service and not an intent service that worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Timer Class, use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) class. It also performs the same repeating tasks you want. AlamrManager is light weight and it runs even if your device is in sleep mode.

Also see this link Android: [How to repeat a service with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012786/2567598)

Answer (score 0):

> For repetitive jobs android provides simple api, called Timer please look it. Very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
      public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            Log.d("Internet Available:  ", ""+flag);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, UpdateWidgetServiceDemo.class);

            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent1, 0);

            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            int i;
            i=15;

            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);


        super.onStart(intent, startId);
      }
```

REMOVE `return START_STICKY;`

Comment: Give me your feedback and if my answer acceptable then accept this.

Comment: your code was hard for me to understand, but thank you for your try, this looks to be working but I can't use code I don't know how should it work.

Comment: It's ok my dear friend.