# Alarm gets trigger randomly but not daily

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The below code triggers alarm randomly at any time, but I want to trigger it only at 8 AM and daily.
What I am missing, please help. Thanks in advance.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, NotifyingDailyService.class);

PendingIntent alarmPIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately 8:00 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

AlarmManager alarmMgr= (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmMgr.cancel(alarmPIntent);

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmPIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question myself by using broadcast rather than service.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, DailyNotificationAlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent alarmPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately 8:00 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

//System.out.println("Alarm set at 8 clock");

Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set at 8 clock", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
AlarmManager alarmMgr= (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.cancel(alarmPIntent);
//alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmPIntent);
//alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,     calendar.getTimeInMillis(),calendar.getTimeInMillis()+ DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, alarmPIntent);          
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,     calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmPIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY is only appropriate for calls to setInexactRepeating().  I think you need to change AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY to the number of milliseconds in a day.

INTERVAL_DAY DOCUMENTATION
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY

ALARM MANAGER EXAMPLE
[Android: How to repeat a service with AlarmManager every 15 minutes, but only run from 8:00AM to 18:00PM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012563/android-how-to-repeat-a-service-with-alarmmanager-every-15-minutes-but-only-ru)

Comment: I have used the setInexactRepeating() but it also triggers randomly.

Comment: I solved the question myself by using broadcast rather than service, anyway thanks.