# Best way to send an email each couple of minutes in android using a BroadcastReceiver, a TimerTask and a AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have a broadcastReceiver that detects when Sim card is changed. I want to send an email each 5 or so minutes with the location of the phone. I have 3 choices in mind :

1. When Sim is changed : start a Service from broadcastReceiver, which starts a TimerTask. Then the TimerTask starts an AsyncTask which sends the email.
2. When Sim is changed : same as point 1, but i start an IntentService instead of a Service.
3. When Sim is changed : start a Service from BroadcastReceiver, which starts an AlarmManager,and then the AsyncTask.

Can you please tell me which one is better and safer?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `IntentService` with `AlarmManager`. When sim card changed, your `broadcastReceiver` should start your intent service, then service send an email and schedule the next time to send. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012786/719212) and make sure you know when to stop sending email to avoid drain battery.

Your service should look like:

```
 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
 {
     // send email.

    // check whether or not sending next time
    if(canSendNextTime()){
        scheduleNextUpdate();
    }
}
```